# How to retrieve the out parameter of an asynchronous method that runs on another thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, out

I created a class `Out<T>`, intending to use it as an `out` parameter in async methods.

```
class Out<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of how I intend to use it:

```
async Task DoWorkAsync(Out<int> arg)
{
    arg.Value = 13;
    await Task.Delay(500); // Placeholder for a really useful async operation
}
```

The `Value` will always be assigned before the first `await` inside the asynchronous method. In other words the assignment will happen in the synchronous part of the method. So the caller can retrieve the value immediately after creating the `Task`, and use it before the awaiting of the `Task`:

```
var arg = new Out<int>();
var task = DoWorkAsync(arg);
Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '13' in the console :-)
await task;
```

Until this point everything works perfectly. The problem appears when it becomes mandatory for the `DoWorkAsync` method to run in a `ThreadPool` thread. Initially I tried the simplest approach with [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run):

```
var arg = new Out<int>();
var task = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(arg));
Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '0' in the console :-(
await task;
```

This didn't work. Another try:

```
var arg = new Out<int>();
var task = Task.Run(async () => await DoWorkAsync(arg));
Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '0' in the console :-(
await task;
```

Didn't work either. After much thought I realized that the current thread cannot retrieve the `arg.Value` until the `ThreadPool` thread has processed the synchronous part of the method, so the current thread must wait. Then, after retrieving the `arg.Value`, the current thread must wait one more time for the asynchronous part of the method. This led me to a solution of the problem:

```
var arg = new Out<int>();
var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWorkAsync(arg),
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskScheduler.Default);
Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '13' in the console :-/
await task;
```

This worked, but I dislike the use of [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew). This is an old-school method, with a bad reputation of [being dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). So my question is: Is it possible to solve this problem, without using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method?

---

**Clarification:** The reason it is mandatory for the `DoWorkAsync` method to run in a `ThreadPool` thread is because it contains a call to a third-party API that I don't trust, and so by calling it directly in the UI thread I risk freezing the UI. So my goal is to retrieve the `Out.Value` immediately after the `DoWorkAsync` returns, without invoking it in the current thread.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201056/discussion-on-question-by-theodor-zoulias-how-to-retrieve-the-out-parameter-of-a).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Task.Run` needs `Wait()` in order to wait for the task to be completed.

A quick test with `Stopwatch` will give us an idea :

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

var arg = new Out<int>();
sw.Start();
var task = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(arg));
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '0' in the console :-(
```

The results :

```
Elapsed: 11ms
0
```

as you can see, the `Task.Run`  didn't wait for the `Task.Delay(500)`.

while if you use `Wait()`

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

var arg = new Out<int>();
sw.Start();
Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(arg)).Wait();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '0' in the console :-(
```

results :

```
Elapsed: 518ms
13
```

it waited for the task to be completed.

compare it with asynchronously wait:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

var arg = new Out<int>();
sw.Start();
var task = DoWorkAsync(arg);
await task;
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.WriteLine(arg.Value); // Prints '13' in the console :-)
```

results :

```
Elapsed: 516
13
```

Comment: My objective is to retrieve the value 13 (almost) immediately. I don't want to await 500 msec to retrieve it. If that was the case I could just change the return value from `Task` to `Task<int>`, then `return 13`, and finally get the value simply by awaiting the task.